# how to set config-constants in FlashBuilder

Tags: apache-flex, flash-builder

in FlashProfessional, there is a concept called "Config constants" which get set in the Publish Settings.  They can be used for conditional compilation as explained here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flash/10.0_UsingFlash/WS3e7c64e37a1d85e1e229110db38dec34-7fa4a.html#WS7D94A7C3-8F91-421a-936C-F076374C470F

Question:  how do you set config constants in the FlexBuilder IDE?

Thanks!

Comment: Read more about [Conditional Compilation using the Flex SDK here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf69084-7abd.html).

Answer (score 1):

Set it in Additional compiler option in the following way: `-define+=CONFIG::isRelease,false`